# Apache NIFI DeleteAzureBlobStorage Processor is Throwing an Error

Tags: apache-nifi

I'm trying to delete all the files present in a particular `Blob`.

I've configured a `DeleteAzureBlobStorage` processor with all the required fields:

```
container name : XXX
Storage Account name : XXX
Storage Account Key : XXX
Blob : ${azure.blobname}
```

But I'm getting the following error:

> DeleteAzureBlobStorage[id] DeleteAzureBlobStorage[id] failed to process session due to The argument must not be null or an empty string. Argument name: deleteSnapshotsOption.; Processor Administratively Yielded for 1 sec: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The argument must not be null or an empty string. Argument name: deleteSnapshotsOption.

Comment: Please share the full error log message. BTW, do you have `azure.blobname` as one of your FlowFile attribute?

Comment: Yes, i was getting the azure.blobname from the upstream but the error says that deleteSnapshotsOption argument cannot be blank. We don't have any attribute with this name and also i was not able to add this as the new attribute.

There are no more errors available other than the one that i have mentioned above. Could you please throw some light on this if you have ever worked with the deleteazureblob processor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah. I just tested a simple flow with `DeleteAzureBlobStorage` and it failed for me as well. It is a bug. A Jira - [NIFI-5698](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-5698) has been created to address this. I have worked on a patch and uploaded it there. If possible, you can try it out and share your results.

Comment: FYI - This bug is now fixed and NiFi 1.8.0 will carry the fix.